# scala match String* generated from xsd with maxOccurs="unbounded"

Tags: scala, xsd, pattern-matching, variadic-functions

I have a xsd with:

```
  <xs:complexType name="records">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

scalaxb generated this code:

```
case class Records(returnValue: String*)
```

I tried this pattern matching:

```
... match {
  case Records(ids: String*) =>
    ...
```

Then the compiler error is:

```
')' expected but identifier found.
        case Records(ids: String*) =>
                                ^
```

I also tried `case Records(ids: Array[String])` and `case Records(ids: Seq[String])`, but with no success.

How can I use scala pattern matching to match this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scala> Records("a", "b") match {
         case Records(strings @ _*) => strings.foreach(println)
       }
a
b


scala> Records("a", "b") match {
         case Records(one) => println("one")
         case Records(one, two) => println("two")
         case Records(one, two, rest @ _*) => println("more than two")
       }
two
```